# Is this number of observations sufficient?

Tags: statistics

I have data about a computer that's been observed for 2000 hours. It has stopped responding 5 times on hours 230, 721, 1578, 1910. Is this data enough to determine the probability distribution of the number of failures?

Comment: That's only four stopping times.

Answer (score 1):

That's not enough points to fit a distribution to, if you have no more information.  But if you know something about the nature of the stoppages you might be able to infer that the number of failures is Poisson, or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the percentage and relative errors. 
If there is a large percentage error to the order of 0.01 to 5%. But if it goes lesser than that it means a small change will alter the standard deviation too much ( and percentage error) . 
As Gregory mentioned if you have a poissions ratio the experiment isn't enough.

Comment: And do add more data about your experiment